# Custom map styling in react-native-maps not rendering, reverts to basic/standard map style

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

Working on a ReactNative App and I am trying to edit the map style.

I am following the instructions on "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps".

For IOS the docs suggest the below.

I.e:

1) Adding a mapStyle = [JSON being generated from https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/].

2) Importing PROVIDER_GOOGLE

3) Adding 'customMapStyle' & 'provider' props (see below)

However, even though I have manually checked the JSON (namely that the colours are all black and grey, as per the custom map I want) The rendered map is still coming out in the standard blue and greens?

Oddly my markers are changing from pins to some android looking pins, so something is happening.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps'

MapStyle = [ ... ]

render() {
  return (
    <MapView
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      customMapStyle={MapStyle}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have any resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did the same mistake of fetching the styles from a local json file and it didn't work. Here's a work around - save the json styles in a `var` and pass it to `customMapStyle`.
Have a read : [Custom google map styles in React Native - medium.com](https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-add-awesome-maps-to-a-react-native-app-%EF%B8%8F-fc7cbde9c7e9)

Answer (score 2):

The reason custom style didn't work for me was that the JSON had outdated parameters so maps defaulted to the default theme. As [ser fiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15052721/ser-fiy) pointed out, make sure to download the JSON from https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: This works, It has 6 ultimate themes, all are tremendous

Answer (score 1):

First go the official side i.e https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and get the json for your style value and copy to the raw folder in resources

And then apply on your onMapready() like this

```
MapStyleOptions mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json);
mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(mapStyleOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a const variable to store the json object. It did not work. Then I changed the const to var and did work for me.