# Removing places from react-native-maps

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps

Adding customMapStyle to MapView in react native works partially & have below issues :-

```
<MapView
    provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    customMapStyle={customMapStyle}
      style={internalStyles.map}
```

Above is mapview in react native & have tried to remove all places icons from map in android/ios but in android only few places are been seen left over in mapview since adding styles was overflowing when generating from https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/, hence looking for clue where is its been said to mapview to remove all kind of places from maps?

In IOS none of maps icon is been removed despite of adding provider tag in mapview, seems like something is missing other that adding provider for IOS, any guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the cloud based map styling instead?

Comment: Or is your issue similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64705869/18422887